# I need to find the differences between the two json files of about 4 GB each

Tags: diff

I need to find the differences between the two json files of about 4 GB each. The files have single line of 4 GB each. I need to find the difference and put it in another file. Is there a free tool to do this task or code in java?

Comment: something like this:

Answer (score 0):

http://json-diff.com/

Try the diff checker or the above link